# ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types / could not convert string to float: for dates

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
appl = pd.read_csv('appl.csv') #apple stock prices taken from finance.yahoo.com

x = appl[['Date', 'Open','High','Low','Close']]
y = pd.to_datetime(appl['Date']) 

import numpy as np
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
model = LinearRegression()
#model.fit(np.isnan(x_train),np.isnan(y_train))
model.fit(x_train,y_train) #<--- receive error on this line
model.coef_
model.intercept_
```

[image: AAPLE Stock]

I get when using `model.fit(x_train,y_train)` the errors ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types
and when not using `model.fit(np.isnan(x_train),np.isnan(y_train))` could not convert string to float:

Comment: Three comments: 1) Using Linear Regression with sequential data (dates) is not the best option, I would recommend use LSTM for example. If you want to keep using LR, I would drop Date feature. 2) When you define `x` and `y`, you will try to predict "Date", using this same feature. This is no correct, since with your input (date) already give you the correct answer. 3) With 'np.isnan()' you obtain Booleans results, so it's not good to train with this results. Before fit, visualizing what are you fitting.

Comment: @AlexSerraMarrugat 1. I am confused, where am I using sequential. Let me read on LSTM & LR, to understand what you are saying / 2. I am using date as a reference for a prediction or date is not being used to predict. / 3. oh ok..  / so you are saying remove date, which I did and got some results, then I thought what was the date the predict was working on, which is how the date came in.  I can't apply the date to the predict at all?

Comment: Which feature you want to predict, and with which features?

Comment: @AlexSerraMarrugat open with date.  Would like to know what I am doing wrong also in the process